# Is there a way to target a nested JSS styled component within another JSS styled component? [JSS-nested/Styled-JSS/Material UI (React)]

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components, jss, css-in-js

Is it possible to target a styled JSS object within another styled JSS object in a similar way  that styled components allows?

Here's an example of what I'm talking about with Styled Components:

```
const Child = styled.div`
  color: red;
`;

const Parent = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  ${Child}:hover {
    color: blue
  }
`;
```

Is this possible in JSS?

Fyi I'm using Material UI v4's styling solution which is based off JSS.

Comment: I could be mistaken but I didn't think you could use backtick's with MUI's styled api

Comment: @Barryman9000 The code example that I gave is not written with JSS/MUI's styled api. It's using styled components to illustrate what I'd like to accomplish with JSS/MUI's styled api.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass your child component to the parent's styled API.

```
const Child = styled("div")({
  color: '#fff'
});
const Parent = styled(Child)({
  background: '#999'
})
```

**UPDATE**

Yeah, I misunderstood. I don't think you can do that with just the MUI `styled` API? The closest I could get was using the `className` prop (or you can use the [classes](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#overriding-styles-classes-prop) prop on MUI components)

```
const Parent = styled('div')({
  background: '#999',
  '& .warning': {
    '&:hover': {
      color: 'goldenrod'
    }
  },
  '& .error': {
    '&:hover': {
      color: 'red'
    }
  }
})

<Parent>
  <Child className="warning">Warning!</Child>
  <Child className="error">Error!</Child>
</Parent>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm looking for a way to target nested instances of "Child" that would be found in "Parent". Unless if I'm missing something, it seems like the example that you gave is creating a styled version of "Child" called "Parent".

Answer (score 0):

use the & ampersands along with brackets `[]` for accomplish that in `JSS`:

```
const Child = styled(div)({
  color: 'red',
});

const Parent = styled(div)({
  display: 'flex',
  [`& ${Child}:hover`]: {
    color: 'blue'
  }
});
```